# How do I properly point sub.domain1.com to sub.domain2.com?

Tags: domains, subdomain

I'm trying to point sub.domain1.com to sub.domain2.com.

They are both hosted on *different* servers.

I've tried changing the CNAME, but that is giving me a "You don't have permission." error when I go to sub.domain1.com in my browser.

Currently, I'm url masking sub.domain1.com to sub.domain2.com, but I don't want to do this for various reasons.

I would like sub.domain1.com url to remain in the address bar.

This is for my mobile site, just an fyi.

Comment: What do you mean by "url masking"?

Comment: My registrar gives me the option to forward one url to another. So you go to URL1 which takes you to URL2, but you only see URL1 in the address bar of the browser. This works for me, but it doesn't feel kosher, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Ah, this sounds like _framed_ forwarding? This won't be particularly good for SEO, if that is a concern.

Comment: I think I've seen it called stealth forwarding as well, but yeah, the SEO implications are the major concern here.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and dirty way:
put an index on sub.domain1.com and do an iframe to sub.domain2.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think that's a little too dirty. It would work though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a *parked domain* at your sub.domain2.com server. Then set the NAMESERVERS on sub.domain1.com to point to domain2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Would this have any effect on domain1 and domain2? Keep in mind that I'm only trying to reroute the subdomain.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this would ordinarily affect the whole domain. I'm not sure how this could be done for a particular subdomain alone.

Comment: I believe my best solution is to get a new host server set up, and change the A record for sub.domain1.com so that it points to the IP of the server.

Comment: You might need to set up something on the domain2.com server so that it knows to accept requests to sub.domain1.com (which is what you are doing when setting up a 'parked domain') - although if you have your own dedicated server with its own IP address...?